# I just lost a sidebar in Files and I have no idea how that happened

Tags: pantheon-files

My laptop had some issues so I restarted it. Before I did, I ran `htop` and killed the process which was using the most of my resources, but I can't remember which one what is.

Once I turned my laptop back on, this happened:

[image: Files without a sidebar]

As you can see, my sidebar completely disappeared and I have no idea why nor how to take it back.

I already tried purging the `pantheon-files` package and installing it again, but that didn't work. It also takes me to the root directory by default instead of my home directory. Running `pantheon-files` from the terminal doesn't show anything suspicious.

**EDIT:** This seems to affect only the current user. I tried logging in as guest and this problem was not present.

Comment: Just as a note, it's not really related with the problem, but don't do things like "Before I did, I ran htop and killed the process which was using the most of my resources, but I can't remember which one what is.". If you really, really, really want to intervene with what your system is doing, make sure you **know** what you are killing, why you do that and remember these facts. They're important.

Comment: Yup, I know. I'll make sure I don't repeat this mistake.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I guess, you have accidentally pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>, it's the short cut for hiding the sidebar.

Comment: I'm 100% sure I didn't press that key combination once I got this problem (as far as I know this key combination doesn't make the / directory default). However, now I did press that key combination and it got the problem resolved once I restarted Files. Now it opens my home directory by default.

Answer (score 2):

The <kbd>F9</kbd> key will hide/show the sidebar as well.