# Sidebar not showing sytsem and USB Devices along with Personals

Tags: pantheon-files

I have elementry OS freya , while working yesterday i did something unknowingly , now my sidebar does not show devices , Below is the screenshot.

[image]

Please help , how can i restore to previous configuration so that devices and Network options are visible again

Answer (score 1):

Close the file manager then run the following commands in a terminal:

```
gsettings reset org.pantheon.files.preferences show-sidebar
```

This may not be necessary, though won't hurt:

```
gsettings reset org.pantheon.files.preferences sidebar-width
```

Comment: I just noticed a [duplicate question](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/830/i-just-lost-a-sidebar-in-files-and-i-have-no-idea-how-that-happened?rq=1) with better answers.